# Do we have to take the dissipation function for the whole system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, dissipation

In lagrangian formalism, The L also known as the lagrangian is taken account of the whole system, for each of its components and parts!

Is this the same for the Rayleigh Dissipation Function?
Like If I have N-pendulum in air drag,
Do I need to find the total dissipation (the sum of the dissipations of each pendulum)?

So What I want to know is that,
Is the dissipation needed to take into account for each components of a dynamical system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.